# main.xml file not found

Tags: android, xml

I am a beginner in android and I am learning it by watching tutorials on YouTube. I completed all the initial steps for building up an android project but I am unable to find out any main.xml file or activity_main.xml file under res/layout folder. In fact, the layout folder is not even showing any drop down menu. I googled my doubts but I am unable to find any satisfactory answer. Can someone please tell me what exactly went wrong ?

Comment: Are you using Eclipse?

Comment: Yes, I am using eclipse...

Comment: Is there a res folder at least?

Comment: Can you post a screenshot?

Comment: ImmortalDev : yes there is a res/layout folder, but nothing is present inside layout folder

Comment: Usually Eclipse automatically makes a (blank) xml file when you tell it to make a new Activity. (File > New > Other > Android Activity)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add your own activity_main.xml file to the layout folder. Right click layout -> New -> Android XML File -> Name the file activity_main and click Finish.

Comment: Thanks... the file is now present... width,height and orientation is present under LinearLayout tags... anything else required ???

Comment: It depends on what you are trying to do. The layout file is essentially a 'blank' screen right now but it will work just fine.

Answer (score 0):

At least if you have the MainActivy.class file, (the launcher activity), the ide, wheater android studio or eclipse should show you if the you layout activity exist by underlining the parameters for the 'setcontentlayout()' function if it doesnt exist. The 'setoptionsmenu()' function also do the same. if they are there, your MainActivity.class should be free from errors otherwise create them and insert them.